# Android Studio resetDrmState message on MediaPlayer release and set to null

Tags: java, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I have a media player that can play 1 of 46 sounds on button click. Instead of keeping 46 media players and stopping them all when I want to play another, I decided to keep 1 and just reuse it. My whole application works perfectly fine but in my Run box I get a resetDrmState message on every button click.

```
V/MediaPlayer: resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
    cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
```

Is this a bad message?
Does anyone know a way to get rid of the message?

I use the code:

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
        String thisIV=view.getTag().toString();
        int resId=getResources().getIdentifier(thisIV,"raw", getPackageName());

        if(mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer=null;
        }

        mediaPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, resId);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

for my media player.